# PYGAME - Edit colours of an image (makes white red at 255,0,0) without numerical python?

Tags: python, image, colors, pygame, numerical

I'm making a simple game, whereby I want my characters quite customizable. I want my characters to be able to be fully edited in colours, for example, if a player wants their character to have cyan skin, they just put into the sliders, or what I choose to use, "0,255,255", or purple "255,0,255", or something random "25,125, 156", and have their character be that colour. I haven't even started creating the game, but I've got the basis down and I know exactly what I must do for pretty much every EXCEPT this.

I done a search in Google, and it turns out, I need numerical python for this? Well this is a whole new package, and in order for the average player to play, I must change it to EXE form... (or have python, pygame and numerical python installed onto their PC, which will be a problem if they have a later version...). Now, it's already getting complex with just pygame, but with numerical python as well, is there even a tutorial on how to do this?

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: so basically you want to make a bitmap that a player can shift colors at runtime?

Comment: if it is: i found an answer here : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26550/how-can-a-pygame-image-be-colored

Comment: Yes, but the answer is about numerical python, which I said without doing. I don't really feel like learning a load more of a program and then not being able to convert my program to exe, since I want everyone to be able to run it.

Comment: if you want to create a program or a game that everyone will be able to run, i suggest learning C and the SDL libary.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use *brute force* method to do this. Here is function to replace color with another in pygame surface.

```
def color_replace(surface, find_color, replace_color):
    for x in range(surface.get_size()[0]):
        for y in range(surface.get_size()[1]):
            if surface.get_at([x, y]) == find_color:
                surface.set_at([x, y], replace_color)
    return surface
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume by `image` you mean `pygame.Surface`.  You have several options:

- `pygame.Surface.set_at(...)`
- Use a palettized surface.  Then change the palette.  Based on your use case, this is actually probably what I'd suggest.
- Use the `pygame.PixelArray` PyGame module.  I don't *think* it requires NumPy.
- Just use NumPy.  It's really not that huge of a requirement; lots of projects require it and it's simple to set up.  You get access to the powerful `pygame.surfarray` module